# Using a matrix in Access, using a row as a column in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a table in Ms-Access, which has two columns, VAR1 and VAR2.

These columns have variables based c1-c2-c3-c4-c5.

The second table is a matrix. I need to use the correlation between VAR1 and VAR2 to get a number from the matrix.

for example:

----TABLE----

VAR1                VAR2

C2                    C2

C1                    C1

C2                    C2

C2                    C3

C1                    C1

C2                    C2

----------MATRIX-----------------

-------VAR2-------

VAR1                C1        C2        C3        C4        C5

C1                    10         16         24         32         40

C2                    16         20         30         40         56

C3                    20         30         40         60         80

C4                    30         40         60         80         160

C5                    40         60         100       160       160

the first row should give me 20, the second 10.

I need a query which will show Var1 values, var2 values, and the results of the matrix (for each row).

FOR EXAMPLE

VAR1   VAR2 MatrixResult

C2       C2          20

C1       C1          10

C2       C2          20

C2       C3          30

C1       C1          10

C2       C5          56

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where the numbers come from (e.g. explain why row C1 column C2 is equal to 16)?

Comment: it is something independent. Let`s say they are values provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest thing I could Think of, Just compare values in case and change the column names accordingly

```
Select m1.var1,m1.var2, 
       Switch ( 
        m1.var2 = "C1", Value =  m2.c1
        m1.var2 = "C2", Value =  m2.c2
        m1.var2 = "C3", Value =  m2.c3
        m1.var2 = "C4", Value =  m2.c4
        m1.var2 = "C5", Value =  m2.c5
       ) As value
    from matrix1 m1,
         Matrix2 m2
   Where m1.var1 = m2.var1
```

Comment: So my question was wrong actually sorry. The query is going to be three columns which are var1, var2, and the result of the matrix

Comment: I think I got your question right this time. The above one checks the var2 and then displays the corresponding value from second  matrix

Comment: It seems correct but somehow I got syntax error. Matrix1 is the table, Matrix2 is the matrix right?

Comment: You used a crosstab query to generate your matrix? Then save the query as 'matrix2' and replace matrix2 in the query by (select * from matrix2) m2

Answer (score 0):

Bit long for a comment so I'll delete/update as appropriate.

It looks like you've got the matrix table set up as it would be used in Excel.
I'd suggest changing the design of the table to have 3 fields.  `Var1`, `Var2` as the Primary Key and `ReturnValue`.
The Primary Key with values C1...C5 would allow 25 records with your matrix values.

I was about to write the SQL to combine the  two tables before realising that you would already have the result you're after in that table.  Rather than the matrix table you have the resulting table should be the matrix you start with.

With that you could extract data with SQL:
`SELECT ReturnValue FROM Matrix WHERE Var1='C1' AND Var2='C2'`
would return 16.

So I guess the next question is:  are you trying to insert the values from your table into a new table/existing table?
This is how that matrix should be stored. Are there just the five columns ow was that an example of the real table?

Comment: the real table is longer, I just simplified them. My question was wrong actually sorry. The query is going to be three columns which are var1, var2, and the results of the matrix.